# how to solve ERROR on proc 0: Cannot open file tersoff.data (../read_data.cpp:1938)?

Tags: physics, lammps

I just started to use lammps and I'm having trouble with reading tersoff. data. How can I solve it

```
lmp_serial.exe -in main.in
LAMMPS (4 Jan 2019)
  using 5 OpenMP thread(s) per MPI task
Reading data file ...
ERROR on proc 0: Cannot open file tersoff.data (../read_data.cpp:1938)
Last command: read_data tersoff.data
```

I'm getting this error

Answer (score 0):

Could you please show the content of `tersoff.data` (at least the first lines) ?

Few things that may help you :

- The file must be in the same folder than `lmp_serial.exe` for Lammps to find it with the command you used.
- For plain text, the file encoding must be readable by Lammps (use UTF8).
- `read_data` takes input files that are formatted as described here : https://lammps.sandia.gov/doc/read_data.html
- Be very careful with any file passed to Lammps, as its way of reading inputs is a bit old-fashioned and inflexible. Any formatting mistake will raise an error.
- If `tersoff.data` describes a Tersoff potential, it has to be read by the [pair_tersoff command](https://lammps.sandia.gov/doc/pair_tersoff.html). In Lammps, `read_data` is only used for setting up the initial position/type of atoms and the simulation box.